Issue with Black Screen Rendering on Equirectangular Projection in Blender
everyone! I’m new to Blender, having started about a month ago, and I’m working on an urgent project. I need help with rendering a globe with a texture of the Earth on it, along with a rectangular legend projected onto the globe using the Shrinkwrap modifier.
Here's my setup:
I have the camera placed at the center of the globe.
I’ve configured the camera to be in panoramic mode, with an equirectangular projection.
When I render, however, I get a completely black screen instead of the expected 360-degree view of my globe with textures, as seen in this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMv_NA_dGm8&t=468s.
What could be causing this black screen? Am I missing something in my render settings or setup?
Note: My goal is to prevent deformation of the legend when I project the final raster onto the globe in the future, so I’m experimenting with this setup to ensure the legend keeps its shape.
Here is my file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/033uoo3dcvz3ybx49toyb/ADBmHRNBztWkpvM51ZNHwJs?rlkey=wlg0dd2oljqw9stnvy92z9iic&st=6676xz1k&dl=0
Thank you in advance for any guidance you can offer!




Hello and welcome. From you image, looks like your camera is blocked by your sphere, causing the black render. Before you render a scene, make sure to get the camera view by pressing NUMBPAD 0 (Zero). You probably need to make your sphere bigger.

There is no illumination inside the globe. The render is black because it’s dark in there. Replace the Principled BSDF shader with an Emission shader (connecting the texture to its Color input) to make the globe glow.
That being said, you might have an easier time just using the globe texture as a world background, and having the legend hover in space with a Track To constraint pointing it at the camera. No sphere involved. My reason for this is that shrink wrapping the legend to the globe surface might not look right on the inside.

Thanks, TheLabCat! The emission shader worked for me and gave the results I needed. The only issue is that when I use the Emission shader, my transparent legend becomes opaque. Is there a way to keep using the Emission shader while also preserving the transparency (alpha)?

Yes. Use a Mix Shader node to switch between the Emission shader and a Transparency shader node, and drive its Factor input with the Alpha channel of the Image Texture.
